# Raspbian 10 - Start menu occasionally resets back to default

Tags: raspbian-buster

I've hidden a lot of software in my start menu on my Raspberry Pi. However, sometimes I'll open it and it'll re-show all of the folders and menu items again. It happens randomly, there's seemingly no pattern.

What is a good way to fix this?